# Function with <input> - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, input

I want to create a table in HTML and add rows below by calling a function with onClick event handler.

Whenever I click for a new row, the text in above row disappeared. Kindly help me.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="con">
    <table border="1" id="budgetMain">
    <tr>
        <th>Serial Number</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Click Here' onClick='myFunc();' />


    <script>
        var serialNumber = 0;
        function myFunc()
        {
          document.getElementById("budgetMain").innerHTML += 
              "<tr><td>" + ++serialNumber + "</td>" +
              "<td><input type='text' id='desc'></td></tr>";
        }
        var description1 = document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML;
    </script>
```

Comment: because innerHTML does not keep values. You should be appending a new row. Look into appendChild

Comment: Could you explain desired behavior? Seems to be working. ** nevermind, got it **

Comment: Is it so hard to format the text and source code in a propper format, so it is easy to read for everyone?